# Issue Logging in With Facebook on iOS App

Tags: ios, facebook, uitableview, facebook-graph-api

In my app, my main screen is a TableView which shows a list of posts from a Facebook Page.  I access those posts using Open Graph, which means a user has to be logged in first.  So, I have it pop up with a UIAlertView which tells the user this.  Clicking ok presents the FBLoginButton, which I have like this:

```
FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
        // Optional: Place the button in the center of your view.
        loginButton.center = self.view.center;
        [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
```

Clicking the Login Button takes me to Facebook, where I give it permission.  It then goes back to the app, but shows an empty TableView with a Facebook Logout button in the middle.  My viewWillAppear in the app is like this:

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/v2.3/PAGEID/feed?limit=20" parameters:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"id, message, full_picture, link" forKey:@"fields"]]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                //performs code to get posts sorted into array


             }
             else {
                 NSLog(@"%@", error);
             }
         }];
    }      else {
        NSLog(@"Not Logged In");
        UIAlertView *login = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Login" message:@"Stronger Marriages now requires a login to Facebook in order to access its latest posts and messages.  Thank you!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [login show];
    }
```

I had thought that once I have given it permission, it would go back to the app, run the viewWillAppear code, and see there was a currentAccessToken and perform the code, but this is not happening.  If I now force close the app, it will show everything fine, with no logout button visible.  How do I get it to do this once it redirects to app after logging in?

Comment: Can you paste your console log when your `viewWillAppear` is called?

Comment: The issue is that viewWillAppear doesn't get called after the app is redirected from Facebook, @Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to respond directly to a login via the `FBSDKLoginButton` is by making your ViewController implement the [`FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate) protocol.

You can call the `loginButton:didCompleteWithResult:error:` function in this protocol to immediately respond to a login as soon as the user returns to your app from Facebook. It would look something like this:

```
- (void) loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton     
    didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
    error:(NSError *)error {
        if ([result token]) {
            // Your code here
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not Logged In");
            // Show error here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `viewWillAppear` doesn't get called, but I have a different solution. When the Facebook token changes, the SDK sends out a notification. You can subscribe to this, perhaps in your `viewDidLoad`, and run your code in the callback.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification
                                                      object:nil
                                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                                  usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                                      NSLog(@"received access token change notif");

                                                      // do your stuff here
                                                  }];
```